# TMX pattern images

Tags: libgdx, gamekit, tiled

I'm looking for a website with patterns to build TMX files, to game tiled maps. I would like to find art designed (sand tiles, grass tiles, sky tiles, stones tiles, vegetables tiles, etc.)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several sources where you can get [tilesets](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tileset&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=mhzGU83qKais0QXQyIHQBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=2560&bih=1539) from.

- [Opengameart.org](http://opengameart.org/)
- [ReinerTilesets.de](http://www.reinerstilesets.de/2d-grafiken/2d-environment/)
- [TomeTik](http://pousse.rapiere.free.fr/tome/)

Just be careful to check the licenses on every art piece, most of them are completely free to use in non commercial projects and most require you to name the author in some way.